# MQTT message from server to client by bridge

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, bridge, qos

How to check, that client, connected by bridge really get messege from server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't (at a MQTT protocol level).

There is no end to end delivery notification in MQTT, if you want to know if a message was delivered you will have to publish another message as an acknowledgement with some unique id from the original message.

Answer (score 1):

MQTT has 3 components subscriber, broker, and producer.
**Producer** sends a data for a topic to broker
**Broker** forwards the same data to all the subscribers for that topic
**Subscriber** gets the data for the subscribed topic

In case you want to know the id of subscribers received the data, just create a **Acknowledge** topic and whoever received the data need to send its ID to Acknowledge Topic. Note this is only if you really want to know the Id's who has received the response.